# Replacing lost SMD capacitor from another board

Tags: capacitor, replacement

I was trying to fix a board and I lost an SMD capacitor.  On the diagram it says "**10UF/6.3V**."

I have another board for another laptop and I found these on the diagram, which one is the compatible with the lost one?

- 10U_0805_6.3V6M > this one I found, but it is bigger than the lost one
- 1U_0402_6.3V4Z
- 1U_0603_6.3V6M
- 1U_0402_6.3V6K

The donor board is not the same as the one that I'm working on.

Is 1U same as 1UF, or they are different?

Comment: Probably 10U_0805_6.3V6M. You didn't mention the physical size of the capacitor, but 0805 is a common size and with effort can be soldered into 1206 or even 0603 pads.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea about the size of the lost one as it not mentioned in the diagram.

Comment: Assuming you have the board in front of you and a ruler you can measure the size of the pads. Alternatively put 0805, 0603, etc parts next to the pads and see which size matches.

Comment: Ok will give it a try, i don't have a ruler right now but I will go to get one and try to measure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UF means microfarad. In this case, since it is a capacitor, U also means microfarad (the Farads are assumed). You may also sometimes see uF or μF or μf.

It seems like none of your donor board parts are exactly compatible. The 10U_0805_6.3V6M is the right capacitance but you said it is the wrong size. Sometimes it is possible to solder parts in even when they are the wrong size. So if you are able to do that, then it should be OK.

6.3V means 6.3 volts which is a common voltage rating for capacitors.

0805 and 0603 and 0402 are the size of the capacitor (the component package size).

They are old size designations, so they are inch-based. 0603 is 0.06 x 0.03 inches. And 0805 is 0.08 x 0.05 inches.

The replacement part is very cheap, but it may be inconvenient to order just one tiny little capacitor from a supply place.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me good information. I will try with another board of the same brand.